# Getting temporal transaction time

Tags: sql-server-2016

Is there a way to get the exact time that SQL Server will use in a temporal table?
My goal is to save it in an audit-like record so that I can link some information with the specific version of the row that was changed.

*Motivation:* I could then get the version that was created during that transaction by using `AS OF saved_time` and I could easily get the version that existed before by querying the Historical table on `sysEndTime = saved_time`.

Looking at query plans, it seems what I want is internally `systrandatetime()` but that is not exposed to T-SQL code.

I tried to use `transaction_begin_time` from `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions` but it's not exactly the same.